# What does signing transactions mean ? and where does it happen?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js

I am having some problems with understand the action of signing transactions on ethereum. i actually never had to do it manually or even using my web3 based Interface. I have seen it used in an example of a "secure" authentification based on the `ethutils` but couldn't really grasp it.

so i want to know what is transactions signing and where and why i would need to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to keep this simple, so the details may not be accurate. See this answer as a primer.

By singing a transaction, you provide proof that you and only you could have created it. Transaction signing is possible, because there exists a relationship between your private key (which you keep secret) and your public key (which can be displayed. Your ethereu address is derived off your public key)

To sign a transaction, the transaction is put into a function which we shall call `Sign`, along with your private key. The output of `Sign` is the signature, which is appended to the transaction message and sent into the network for mining.

To proof that a transaction was signed by the owner of the private key of an address, another function is used, which we'll call `Verify`. `Verify` takes two inputs: your transaction,and the signature. The output of this function is your public key, which can translated to your address. A transaction is valid, if, and only if, the address that can be derived from the output of `Verify`, is the same as the address of the sender of the message.

This way, transacations can only be done by the person that has access to the private key.